# Will a base destructor always be called when a derived object is deleted?

Tags: c++

say I have the following:

```
class Foo {
public:
void destroy();
~Foo()
{
   destroy();
}
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
~Bar() {}
};
```

If I have a Bar object, will Foo's destructor be called when the Bar objected is deleted?

Thanks

Comment: Base classes should either have a virtual destructor, or a protected destructor. Deleting through a base class pointer when it doesn't have a virtual destructors leads to UB, plain and simple. Either satisfy that requirement, or prevent a deletion from occurring.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.

But the above code is dangerous; if you don't declare `~Foo()` as `virtual`, then `~Bar()` won't be called if you invoke `delete` on a `Bar` object via a `Foo *`.

Comment: Technically it's UB, but that is the most common method of failure. +1 anyway.

Comment: That's true, but not what the question asks. It asks if `Foo`'s destructor will always be called, to which the answer is yes.

Comment: @Billy: That's what I wrote as my first word!

Comment: The other option is to make the base-class destructor protected. That means you cannot call delete on it, but avoids having a v-table when you don't need one. There are sometimes reasons you want a base-class for inheritance or a non-polymorphic reason eg exposing a smaller interface to users or even binding a const-reference to it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes this will work if you hold a `Bar` reference.  However this is a very fragile solution because it does not work the other way around (holding a `Foo&` or `Foo*` which points to a `Bar`).  In order for this to work `Foo`s destructor must be virtual.  Otherwise it will do non-virtual dispatch and only call the destructor on `Foo`.

```
class Foo { 
public: 
void destroy(); 
virtual ~Foo() 
{ 
   destroy(); 
} 
}; 

class Bar : public Foo { 
public: 
virtual ~Bar() {} 
};
```

In the general case where inheritance is expected the types involved should be marked with a virtual destructor.  Like most rules though this is not true 100% of the time.  But rather than get into all of the cases here I encourage you to read question #2 in the following article (thanks for the link Steve)

- http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Comment: "should be standard practice" - unless the destructor is protected.

Comment: @Steve, I intentionally left that statemen as non-concrete because there are valid scenarios where destructors do not need to be virtual. I didn't want to dive into them all so chose a nice vague sounding best practice statement :)

Comment: fair enough. Anyone reading who wants to know what we're talking about, I think http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm is a good analysis ("Virtual Question #2").

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the nice link. Updated my answer to include it

Answer (score 2):

You make the base class's destructor virtual if the derived class could possibly have anything important going on.  In fact, you should make it virtual if there's pretty much any chance someone will derive from your class.

- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7

In any case, if you implement a destructor, you should also implement the Big-3:

- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.10

Here's some code that should make the behavior of a virtual destructor obvious:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1
{
public:
  ~Base1() // Uh-oh, not virtual...
  {
    std::cout << "~Base1()\n";
  }
};

class Derived1 : public Base1
{
public:
  ~Derived1()
  {
    std::cout << "~Derived1()\n";
  }
};

class Base2
{
public:
  virtual ~Base2() // Good, it's virtual...
  {
    std::cout << "~Base2()\n";
  }
};

class Derived2 : public Base2
{
public:
  ~Derived2()
  {
    std::cout << "~Derived2()\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Simple Base1: ";
  Base1* b1 = new Base1();
  delete b1;

  std::cout << "Simple Base2: ";
  Base2* b2 = new Base2();
  delete b2;

  std::cout << "Simple Derived1: ";
  Derived1* d1 = new Derived1();
  delete d1;

  std::cout << "Simple Derived2: ";
  Derived2* d2 = new Derived2();
  delete d2;

  std::cout << "Polymorphic Derived1: ";
  b1 = new Derived1();
  delete b1;

  std::cout << "Polymorphic Derived2: ";
  b2 = new Derived2();
  delete b2;

  return 0;
}
```

> Simple Base1: ~Base1()
>   
> Simple Base2: ~Base2()
>   
> Simple Derived1: ~Derived1()
>   
> ~Base1()
>   
> Simple Derived2: ~Derived2()
>   
> ~Base2()
>   
> Polymorphic Derived1: ~Base1() **Note -** *I read on another answer that this behavior is undefined, but that's just as bad, if not worse.  Basically, make sure your base class has a virtual destructor*
>   
> Polymorphic Derived2: ~Derived2()
>   
> ~Base2()

Comment: Virtual-ness has nothing to do with whether or not the BASE class has complicated logic. Only Derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be a bit pedantic here and say "Yes, but there are cases when the answer would be No". For example:

```
class Foo {
public:
  void destroy();
  ~Foo()
  {
    destroy();
  }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
  ~Bar() { exit (0); } // code never returns from exit call so base class
                       // destructor never executed!
};
```

Throwing an exception may also interrupt the normal destructor sequence. Also, any undefined behaviour in a destructor would eliminate the guarentee that base class desctructors are called (because anything could happen).

But generally, the base class destructor is called after the derived class destructor has completed.

Comment: Throwing an exception from a destructor is bad idea because it will terminate if it is handling another exception. Not sure about base-class destructors, they'd probably be called anyway if there is no terminate in the call-stack unwind, but you should still not do it.

Answer (score -5):

You need to declare the destructor 'virtual' in the base class to get that behavior.

Comment: You should add in the note (as Oli Charlesworth says) that the use of `virtual` is necessary in the case where you would be deleting via a base class pointer `Foo*`. If you had a `Bar *`, deleting it would also delete the `Foo` object.

Comment: @Als, see Merlyn Morgan-Graham's answer where he shows that it works.